# Слой наложений на изображение с использованием position: absolute, при position: relative у изображения, выходит за рамки изображения

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Слой наложений на изображение с использованием position: absolute, при position: relative у изображения, выходит за рамки изображения. Как это можно исправить?(Если что здесь используется bootstrap)

```css
.bg4 {
 height: 5255px;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.s4_title_container {
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.s4_title {
 text-align: center;
 color: #3b434c;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 35px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-top: 99px;
}

.s4_title_span {
 color: #f7600e;
}

.s4_under_title {
 text-align: center;
 color: #3b434c;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-bottom: 99px;
}

.s4_imges {}

.s4_img_item {
 margin-right: 29px;
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.s4_img {
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
}

.s4_img_content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 background-color: #f7600e;
 border-radius: 10px;
 opacity: 0.9;
}

.s4_img_content_container {
 max-width: 260px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.s4_img_content_title {
 padding-top: 87px;
 margin-bottom: 22px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.s4_img_content_under_title {
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.s4_img_content_btn {}

.s4_btn {
 margin-top: 92px;
 padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.s4_btn_img {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 width: 210px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #d8d9db;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #3b434c;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 33.333333%;
}
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg4">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="s4_title_container">
            <h2 class="s4_title">
                OUR <span class="s4_title_span">WORKS<span>
            </h2>
            <p class="s4_under_title">
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="s4_imges d-flex flex-wrap">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="s4_img_item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50" alt="img" class="s4_img">
                    <div class="s4_img_content d-flex flex-column">
                        <div class="s4_img_content_container">
                            <h3 class="s4_img_content_title">
                                ABAZOO WEBSITE 
                            </h3>
                            <p class="s4_img_content_under_title">
                                Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
                    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            </p>
                            <a href="" class="s4_img_content_btn">

                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="s4_img_item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50" alt="img" class="s4_img">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="s4_img_item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50" alt="img" class="s4_img">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="s4_img_item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50" alt="img" class="s4_img">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="s4_img_item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50" alt="img" class="s4_img">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="s4_img_item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50" alt="img" class="s4_img">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 collapse" id="s4_show_more">
                <span class="d-flex justify-content-center">SHOW MORE</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="s4_btn d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data- 
          toggle="collapse" data-target="#s4_show_more" aria- 
          controls="s4_show_more" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
          navigation">
                <span class="s4_btn_img">
                    Show More
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image: Н]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block__text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.block:hover .block__text {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c11496/v11496584/1603/HrXDksORiAs.jpg?ava=1">
  <div class="block__text">Котик №1</div>
</div>
<div class="block"><img src="https://sun1-84.userapi.com/c855420/v855420510/115983/BuLonSnoMAY.jpg?ava=1">
  <div class="block__text">Котик №2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

А как, по-вашему, `position:relative` у изображения в принципе должен был повлиять на элемент, находящийся ВНЕ его?

Поставьте `position:relative` общему контейнеру изображения и наложения.

Comment: А если у этого контейнера есть margin, это будет как либо влиять на этот слой?

Comment: Если маргин будет влиять на этот контейнер (смещать его), то,  соответственно, все его содержимое будет двигаться вместе с ним.

Comment: Спасибо, помог. Что-то я затупил.